# UITableViewCell Did Selected the subviews backgroundcolor are changed

Tags: ios, uitableview

The view on the right bottom added at the imageview , when i select the cell, the bgcolor will changed ,how avoid this happen?

thanks.

> Image Before Selection

[image: before selected]

> Image after Selection

[image: selected]

Comment: if don't want selection color set tableview selection color to none

Answer (score 1):

Change your cell's selection style to none either programmatically or from storyboard.

If you want to do it programmatically, you can may write this code in your cell's awakeFromNib method.

```
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: but i want to change the cell backgroundcolor when  isSelected.

Comment: i guess you want to change the background of the imageView rather than the whole cell, am I correct?